# Indentation not aligning while using algorithm2e package

Tags: algorithm2e, pseudocode

Below is my latex:

```latex
\usepackage[ruled,longend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{algorithm}
    $I \gets \text{Images of objects' plane}$\newline
    $Detector \gets \text{Define detector}$\newline
    $Descriptor \gets \text{Define Descriptor}$\newline
\end{algorithm}
```

But the first line is un aligned

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line-ends within an `algorithm` environment under [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) require the use of `\;`, not `\newline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,longend]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  $I \gets \text{Images of objects' plane}$\;
  $\text{Detector} \gets \text{Define detector}$\;
  $\text{Descriptor} \gets \text{Define Descriptor}$\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If you don't like the semicolons printed, then add

```
\DontPrintSemicolon
```

somewhere after loading `algorithm2e`.

Comment: Would `\DontPrintSemicolon` remove all the semicolons in the text or just in the algorithm section?

Comment: @paul-shuvo: Just the semicolons associated with `\;` within the `algorithm` environment.